# How to use slug in URL with generic view?

Tags: python, django, django-views

How can I view a single article by it's headline like so: `news/article_name`?

I managed to make it work with numbers (`<int:pk>` in urls then access it in template using `{% url 'article' article.id %}`) so `news/1` actually worked. Instead of using numbers I want to use headlines and can't figure out how.

**models.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):
headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
content = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.headline
```

**urls.py**

```
path('<slug:headline>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='article'),
```

**views.py**

```
class ArticleView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'news/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'article'
    local_context = {**context, **{'show_comments':False}}
```

**somewhere in article template**

```
<p><a href="{% url 'article' %}">Read more</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you used the primary key you had to include that in the URL tag.

```
{% url 'article' article.id %}
```

In the same way, you have to include the headline in the URL tag.

```
{% url 'article' article.headline %}
```

Note that it might be better to include a separate [slug field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) instead of using `headline`, so that you get URLs like `/news/man-bites-dog` instead of `/news/Man%20Bites%20Dog`

```
class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

Then you would change the url tag to:

```
{% url 'article' article.slug %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your slug should be a [`SlugField()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#slugfield). You can use the utility [`slugify()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) to generate a url-friendly string based on your headline.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    ... your other fields ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.headline)
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I used https://github.com/iplweb/django-autoslug-iplweb to auto populate slug field.